# python: trying to set value in getter, results in object has not attribute

Tags: python-3.x, properties, pytest

EDIT: This was my bug. After changing to using properties, I needed to check every instance of access to what was previously a variable, and make deal with situations when I was access the variable in **init**.

Due to a static variable, I had a code path on subsequent runs that was causing this bug.

In a class to manage an API, I have the issue that the auth token can expire. I have added a timestamp and a 'getter' via the @property decorator. I've added a setter too. I thought this would be a nice way to intercept requests for tokens about to expire and replace them with a new one, without having to touch any of the code which uses the token, which was until now simply an instance value, and an expired token lead to an exception, which I rarely encountered.

EDIT: Python 3.8.2 under 64 bit linux

When I run a single test, it works fine.
If I run two tests in the same pytest run, the second test fails while setting up the connection object, even though the code to create the object is identical.

My debugger indicates that when I try to assign the variable in **init**

```
self.__token = value
```

it invokes the getter. The same happens with self.token, which is also not what I expected.

My getter has a check for the timestamp expiring, but the timestamp is set with the current time when initialising the object, so that check is not invoked. It goes straight to:

```
@property
def token(self):
...
    
    return self.__token
```

and I'm getting the exception:

```
'EnhancedZohoAnalyticsClient' object has no attribute '_ReportClient__token'
```

The `EnhancedZohoAnalyticsClient` is a derived class, the property is on the base class `ReportClient`.

I don't understand why the getter is being called even when I assign to the __token variable.
I also don't understand why this only happens on the second (and subsequent tests). The same test passes if I make it the only test I run.

I thought it may be something to do with pytest fixtures, so i removed the use of the a fixture to set up the EnhancedZohoAnalyticsClient class. Now I create it in the test.
But same problem.

Comment: Do you have a setter for the same property that perhaps invokes the getter? I.e. by checking the value in `self.token` or something similar (in regards to why the getter is even being called, not why the exception occurs). Also, are you setting `self.__token` in the `__init__` method of `EnhancedZohoAnalyticsClient` or `ReportClient`?

Comment: Never mind the first question in my comment - I just realized you assigned to `self.__token` rather than `self.token` so no setter should be invoked (unless the setter is for `self.__token` for some reason)

Comment: `self.__token` is set in the ReportClient class (the base class). But you're right! On the second call, a class 'static' variable is set, which means there is a different code path in my code and I am creating a header which accesses the token which calls the getter! That must be it.

Comment: Ah gotcha, hopefully that fixes it for you!

Comment: I was asking about which class's `__init__` you set it in in case it was mangling to the wrong class but it seems like you probably unintentionally accessed the property before setting it instead